# D3.js: Measure frame rate

Tags: javascript, performance, d3.js, svg

Is there a good way to measure the number of frames drawn per second when rendering SVG?

I am working on a plot and wish to measure the render performance, but aside from the Chrome performance tools I'm not sure how to do so.

If there are helpers in the D3 ecosystem analogous to the stats package often used inside render loops, I'd be happy to look at that...

Comment: Outside browser built in performance tools, no. Such functionality if open to general javascript such as d3 would likely be a privacy risk.

Comment: Interesting--can you say more about the potential security implications you're thinking about? If there are articles that discuss the topic I'm happy to check them out! Also, if you make this an answer with maybe a reference, I'm happy to accept it!

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=711043

Answer (score 0):

The same approach one uses in three.js appears to work in d3.js:

```js
const getSize = () => ({
  w: window.innerWidth,
  h: window.innerHeight,
})

/**
* Config
**/

const k = 1;
const zoomBounds = [0.5, 32]; // min max zoom bounds
let size = getSize();

/**
* SVG
**/

const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('id', 'scene')
  .attr('viewBox', [0, 0, size.w, size.h]);

/**
* Add grid
**/

const gGrid = svg.append('g').attr('id', 'grid');

const grid = (g, x, y) => {
  g
  .attr('stroke', '#eaeaea')
  .attr('stroke-opacity', 1)
  .call(g => g
    .selectAll('.x')
    .data(x.ticks(10 * k))
    .join(
      enter => enter.append('line').attr('class', 'x').attr('y2', size.h),
      update => update,
      exit => exit.remove()
    )
    .attr('x1', d => x(d))
    .attr('x2', d => x(d)))
  .call(g => g
    .selectAll('.y')
    .data(y.ticks(12 * k))
    .join(
      enter => enter.append('line').attr('class', 'y').attr('x2', size.w),
      update => update,
      exit => exit.remove()
    )
    .attr('y1', d => y(d))
    .attr('y2', d => y(d)));
}

const gVertex = svg.append('g')
  .attr('id', 'vertices')
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round');

/**
* Domains
**/

const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-100, 100])
  .range([0, size.w])

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([-100, 100])
  .range([size.h, 0])

/**
* Add zoomability
**/

const zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent(zoomBounds) // set bounds of zoomable area
  .on('zoom', function() {
    const transform = d3.event.transform; // contains zoom depth and x, y coords
    const zx = transform.rescaleX(x).interpolate(d3.interpolateRound);
    const zy = transform.rescaleY(y).interpolate(d3.interpolateRound);
    // run zoom operation on text layer
    gVertex.attr('transform', transform);
    // set the size of the text

    // update the grid sizing
    gGrid.call(grid, zx, zy);
  });

svg.call(zoom).call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);

/**
* Stats
**/

const stats = new Stats();
stats.showPanel(0);
document.body.appendChild(stats.dom);

/**
* Render
**/

function render() {
  // fetch data from api
  const data = ["Curtis Gilbert", "Ann Boyd", "Kimberly Hicks", "Dawn Braun", "Gabriela Vega", "Cory Morgan", "Stuart Lopez", "Anthony Paul", "Jeffrey Frye", "Andre Nicholson", "Jeffrey Summers", "Kayla Jackson", "Melissa Campbell", "Lisa Rodriguez", "Kevin Hernandez", "Mr. Dean Brooks", "Angela Mckinney", "Gabrielle Stewart PhD", "Vanessa Massey", "Mr. Jose Mcdonald MD", "Jennifer Brown", "Albert Baxter", "Chris Todd", "Vanessa Leonard", "Kevin Johnson", "Spencer Martinez", "Linda Lee", "Lauren Stewart", "Chad Powell", "Jennifer Mathis", "Elizabeth Webster", "James Patterson MD", "Brandon Davidson", "David Evans", "Kathleen Pena", "Donald Osborne", "Sarah Ross", "Jeremy Burke", "Matthew Miller MD", "Janet Abbott", "Andrew Miller", "Anthony Mack", "Joshua Gomez", "Glenn Doyle", "Joseph Hall", "James Martin", "Roger Delgado", "Shannon Jimenez", "Christina Thompson", "Angela Moore", "Lisa Hatfield", "Stephen Wilson", "Janice Wong", "Jon Frey MD", "Veronica Booker", "Jennifer Martinez", "James Santiago", "Linda Singleton PhD", "Heidi Hill", "Timothy Torres", "Jonathan Reid", "Brittney White", "Amanda Gomez", "Katelyn Richards", "Christian Macdonald", "Michelle Hunt", "Francisco Herrera", "Hector Sherman", "Adam Arias", "Rita Murray", "Thomas Wood", "Robert Munoz", "Mark Richard", "Barbara Mckay", "Sabrina Buck", "Mrs. Regina Murphy", "Derek Pace", "Edward Lucas", "Nancy Bailey", "George Brown", "John Turner", "Leroy Holt", "Audrey Nunez", "Crystal Thompson", "Isaac Butler", "Keith Guzman", "Stephanie Holland", "Nicole Pugh", "Megan Bauer", "Derek Green", "Miranda Ellis", "Hannah Buckley", "Sergio Cox", "Andrea Wood", "Stephen Walker", "Michelle Smith", "Carl Brown", "Gerald Mejia", "Mary Monroe", "Corey Moore"]  

  // draw the points
  const vertices = gVertex.selectAll('.vertex').data(data)

  vertices.enter()
    .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'vertex')
      .attr('x', d => Math.random() * 300)
      .attr('y', d => Math.random() * 300)
      .text(d => d)
}

/**
* Main
**/

function animate() {
  stats.begin();
  render();
  stats.end();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stats.js/16/Stats.js'></script>
  </head>
  <style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
  }

  html,
  body,
  svg {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
  }

  text {
    fill: black;
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  </style>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

As long as all the action happens inside the render loop, you can measure performance with Stats.js...

Comment: That's not measuring rendering at all, it's measuring DOM insertion.

Comment: If all updates happen inside that render loop and it's called each animation frame, won't we measure the number of frames per second?

Comment: no, we carefully prevent you measuring frames per second to protect your privacy.

Comment: I guess I'm confused. Are you saying there's no relationship between RequestAnimationFrame and SVG DOM work? If there is a relationship, can you help to clarify how the SVG work is allowed to carry on outside an RAF call?

Comment: you can update the DOM i.e. the data and time that. Rendering i.e. updating what you see on the screen takes place separately.

Comment: So the DOM updates will extend the duration of an animation frame but DOM updates have no necessary bearing on what's painted on the screen during a particular frame?

Comment: DOM updates kick off an asynchronous paint. Many DOM updates can contribute to a single paint i.e. they are batched. The paint calls back into the DOM so it paints whatever the DOM state is at the moment of the paint.

Comment: Thanks very much for confirming. If you write these notes up as an answer, I'll be happy to delete this one and accept yours!